# How to create ConsumerGroups for Eventhub programatically using nodejs in Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, azure-node-sdk

How to create consumergroups in eventhub using nodejs in Azure?

I tried to replicate what .net SDK offers, it did not work.

```
const { NamespaceManager } = require("@azure/service-bus");                                                                                                   
let namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(eventHubConnectionString);                                                                 
let ehd = namespaceManager.GetEventHub(eventHubPath);                                                                                                         
namespaceManager.CreateConsumerGroupIfNotExists(ehd.Path, consumerGroupName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the process that worked:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/create-consumer-group

**Steps:**

1. Create SAS Token
2. Supply the right headers and make a https call to REST api
3. You can create it only once, if you call for the second time, it will throw an 409 error. If you want an update or insert call, you need to check for it.

**SAS Token:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token

uri -- url of your eventhub
saName -- Name of your Managed Policy
saKey  -- Primary / Secondary Key of your EventHub Manage Policy (Ensure it has the Manage)

```
function createSharedAccessToken(uri, saName, saKey) { 
    if (!uri || !saName || !saKey) { 
            throw "Missing required parameter"; 
        } 
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri); 
    var now = new Date(); 
    var week = 60*60*24*7;
    var ttl = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000) + week;
    var signature = encoded + '\n' + ttl; 
    var signatureUTF8 = utf8.encode(signature); 
    var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', saKey).update(signatureUTF8).digest('base64'); 
    return 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encoded + '&sig=' +  
        encodeURIComponent(hash) + '&se=' + ttl + '&skn=' + saName; 
}
```

**Request Parameters:**

**URL:**

> https://your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/your-event-hub/consumergroups/testCG?timeout=60&api-version=2014-01

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
Host: your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net
Authorization: {replace with the content from your SAS Token}
```

**Payload:**

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">  
   <content type="application/xml">  
      <ConsumerGroupDescription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Any name you want</ConsumerGroupDescription>  
   </content>  
</entry>
```

**Possible Return Statuses:**

```
201 -- Successful Creation
404 -- Not found, you are using a name that does not exist
409 -- The messaging entity 'XXX' already exists.
```

If you notice any other issues, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Event hubs Node.JS SDK doesn't support management operations.

Try a management client like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventHub/

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that. There is no way to do with nodejs to create consumergroup ?

Comment: You can still do REST in JS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/consumergroups/createorupdate

Comment: Using the management api, is one of the wrong way of doing it for this purpose.

Comment: The corresponding JavaScript library is https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/arm-eventhub.  Curious why do you think using the management api is the wrong way?